# Denote Half the Width of a Column in a Two-Column Document

Tags: two-column

I want to denote in a command the half of the width of a column in a two-column document.

When I want to do the same in a normal document I write `0.5\textwidth`, but how do I do the same for the half of the width of the columnn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width of a column is `\linewidth` or `\columnwidth`. See for example

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]

\includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

[image]